# libGdx. using Intent to call a class in other project

Tags: java, android, android-intent, libgdx

When I created a libgdx game project. I got two folders.. 
1. Gdx_game
2. Gdx_game_android

I created the game. Now I have to implement GameOver screen. this gameover .java class is stored in gdx_game_Android.

So, now in gdx_game, mygdxgame.java tells me when the game is over. And in gameover method of mygdxgame.java, i want to call GameOver.java class of 2nd folder.

How do I do this?

I tried

```
Intent in = new Intent(this, GameOver.class);
startActivity(in);
```

Simply, I want to access a java class of one folder from other folder.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how you do it in LiBGDX. LiBGDX is cross platform. It won't have any Android specific code. You need to do all the coding in the Gdx_game and then just use the Gdx_game_android project to open the Gdx_game like:

```
public class Gdx_Game_Android extends AndroidApplication  {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    config.useAccelerometer = false;
    config.useCompass = false;
    config.useGL20 = true;
    initialize(new Gdx_game(this), config);
}
}
```

**EDIT:**

I think you need to learn LibGDX from basics. Read the [documentation](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/documentation.html) or follow [this tutorial](http://obviam.net/index.php/getting-started-in-android-game-development-with-libgdx-create-a-working-prototype-in-a-day-tutorial-part-1/).